# Issue with export JS file in angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, import, angular-cli

I am trying to export (and use) js file to angular application.

Export if JS file:

```
export const someExport= {
  someExportProp: ...
}
```

import in angular:cli.json:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../src/modules/myJs.js",
    "../node_modules/muicss/dist/js/mui.min.js"
  ],
```

Usage in component:

```
import { myJs} from '@core/myJs'
```

And I have next error with reference to my js file:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Can someone help me?

Comment: it should be a TS file not a js file to use `export` . Javascript in browser does not understands `export`

Comment: Maybe I can fix it?

Comment: Did you write the export in a TS file?